# Dynamically load view into page on click

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS app which looks like this:

[image]

The user clicks and drags objects from the left into the scene on the right. The entire page is a view that is loaded by the $routeProvider. I want to make it so that when the user clicks on an item that is in the scene, an information box will come up below showing properties associated with that object and so on (as shown at the bottom of the image above).

I'm assuming that I would need to give an ng-click attribute to each object that has been dragged into the scene, and then in the method associated with the ng-click, do something that will load in a view that shows the info box, but I'm not really sure how to do this.

Comment: read about ng-include

Comment: I've read about ng-include but I'm not exactly sure how to use it to dynamically load a view. Would I just create a string containing a div with the ng-include attribute set to the path to the view, then $compile the string and append it to the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need someway to store a reference to the selected item, and then reference a property of that object in an `ng-include` directive.

An easy way to do this is to set some controller for the entire page which manages the selected item.

```
function SomeHighLevelController($scope) {
    $scope.selectedItem = { viewUrl: 'someDefaultContent.html' };
    $scope.setSelectedItem = function(item) {
        $scope.selectedItem = item;
    }
}
```

And then the selected item would have a property called `viewUrl` or some such.

```
{
    // other properties
    viewUrl: 'ballDetails.html'
}
```

And the view would be something like:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeHighLevelController">
   <div id="objects" ng-controller="SomeMadeUpControllerName">
       <!-- and all the junk in here -->
   </div>
   <div id="scene" ng-controller="SomeOtherMadeUpControllerName">
       <!-- and all the junk in here -->
   </div>
   <div id="details" ng-include src="selectedItem.viewUrl">
   </div>
</div>
```

When an item is clicked on, you call the `setSelectedItem` method and pass the object that was clicked on.  The rest happens automagically.